# Move daemon to its own non admin user account

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, httpd

I am running a Ubuntu server instance. It's on EC2 so the default setup is a admin account(I know it's not root) named Ubuntu. I have already installed Apache HTTP 2.4 from source,  but realized I would like to run Apache HTTPD under a non admin user account named Apache. Any suggestions for making Apache HTTPD run under its own account?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache httpd switches to a different user already by default. On Ubuntu have a look in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` at `User` parameter which uses a variable defined in `/etc/apache2/envvars`. If you are not happy with the default user `www-data` you can change it there.

If you want to start the daemon as non-root user from the very beginning, you will have to modify the `/etc/init.d/apache2` startup script. That will be problematic, for example it will not be able to listen on port 80, it will not be able to write its `.pid` file in `/var/run` etc.

Comment: All I want is the safest setup possible. Apache and MongoDB both suggest running the daemon under its own account. I was confused how to do that but it seems like they automatically do it and they are referring to people who changes default settings.